# How to bold a single tick on X axis in a histogram?

Tags: r, histogram

I have a histogram whose x axis values go from -500 to + 500. I want to highlight the 0 mark on x axis. I was thinking of making the tick on 0 bold and more pronounced. Any suggestions?

Some sample code,

```
hist(runif(100,-500,500))
```

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
set.seed(101)
hist(runif(100,-500,500))
axis(side=1,lwd=0,lwd.ticks=4,at=0,lend=1,labels=FALSE,tcl=-1)
```

Specify `lend=1` to get the line end not to extend above the axis.
See `par` for more information about `tcl` and `lend`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get the tick *label* at 0 bold too, you have to specify all the tick locations manually, so you can easily omit 0:

```
set.seed(101)
hist(runif(100,-500,500), axes=FALSE)
axis(side=1, at=seq(-500, 500, 100)[-6])  # omit 0 (the 6th element of the sequence)
axis(side=1, at=0, lwd=0, lwd.ticks=par("lwd"), font=2)
```

You could also combine this with @ben-bolker's suggestion to use `lwd.ticks=4` (instead of `lwd.ticks=par("lwd")`) if you want the tick line thicker too.